# How to detect whether a zip/compressed file is completely unziped/uncompressed?

Tags: java, file-io, zip, file-locking

I have a java program to copy a folder(along with all files in it) from one location to another programatically.Now assume user pasted a zip file in this folder and then unzips it.Meanwhile my program starts,then it copies only the files which got unzipped in the folder.I want to wait till this unzipping of files is finished.

Hence I am looking for a programmatical way using which I can detect that the zip file has been completely uncompressed and then only resume with the normal copying of files.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some details about the env. OS JVM versions. etc

Comment: You mean you're doing this *concurrently* with the unzip??  About all you can do is look for a .zip suffix.  But I know of no auto-unzipper that will automatically unzip internal zip files.

Comment: (Seems to me you have to know the unzip is running and wait for it to finish.)

Comment: Your problem does not seems to be detecting if a file is zipped or not.
You need to prevent concurrent access in this directory.

Comment: Maybe you need to describe the problem you're actually trying to solve.  You approach seems like a poor solution to a larger problem.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can rename the file that's beeing unpacked. If it's not "renamable" then the file is probably locked.

Comment: That only works on Windows. Also, if the user doesn't exit the unzipper, the process will block.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reliable way to do this because you have no control over the unzipper; for example, the user could decide to unzip only some of the files. Since the unzipper won't tell you what the user selected in the UI, there is no reliable way to know when "all" files have been unpacked.

Workarounds:

1. Users must unzip files in a different folder and then *move* the files into the folder that you watch. Move operations on the same disk are atomic, so this will make sure you get only complete files.
2. Accept ZIP archives as input and unpack them yourself. That way, you have full control over the unpack process and can make sure you only process complete files. Also, since the ZIP "table of contents" is at the end of the ZIP archive, this will also make sure that you only process complete ZIP archives.